# DismissViewControllerAnimated not working with navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my application i have used the following code to implement after dismissing the view i have pushed to new view,When i tried to implement the view is not dismissing instead it overlapping.Here my code,

```
-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
 {
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
   {
    UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
 }
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
             editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
 {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    cropingImageViewCon = [[CropingImageViewControl alloc]initWithNibName:@"CropingImageView" bundle:nil];
    cropingImageViewCon.delegate = self;
    cropingImageViewCon.originalImg = image;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:cropingImageViewCon animated:YES];
    }];
  }
```

Whats wrong with my code,Can any one please help out.

Comment: How did you present the picker in the first place?

Comment: @MikePollard i have update the quest code.Please check

Comment: What view are you expecting should be dismissing? Looking at the code, the imagepicker view should be dismissing, after that the cropingImageViewCon view should be presented modally over the view that has the control that calls selectExitingPicture

Comment: Do you want to push into CropingImageViewControl after dismissing ImagePicker?

Comment: @Marcel when i do that it shows `Attempt to present <View2: 0x817a7d0> on <UINavigationController: 0x81721a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Thats tells you that the controller (which has the control that's calling selectExitingPicture), is not the UINavigationController's rootViewController. The UINavigationController is not part of the window hierarchy at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push into `CropingImageViewControl` then you are going wrong way,

Use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewCotrollerObject animated:YES];
```

instead of using `presentModalViewController:`